# ArgumentError in Articles#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working with Jumpstartlab blogger tutorial. When I run server and I want open article I am getting following error:

```
ArgumentError in Articles#show

Showing /home/darek/rails_projects/blogger/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb where line 
#3 raised:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Extracted source (around line #3):

 1  <h3>Post a Comment</h3>
 2
 3  <% form_for [ @article, @comment ] do |f| %>
 4  <p>
 5     <%= f.label :author_name %><br/>
 6     <%= f.text_field :author_name %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
     <h3>Post a Comment</h3>

      <% form_for [ @article, @comment ] do |f| %>
        <p> 
            <%= f.label :author_name %><br/>
            <%= f.text_field :author_name %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <% f.label :body %><br/>
            <% f.text_area :body %>
        </p>
        <p>
            <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
        </p>
         <% end %>
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    article_id = params[:comment].delete(:article_id)

    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.article_id = article_id

    @comment.save

    redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
  end

end
```

I've tried to compare code with github repository of tutorial but it didn;t help. The tutorial was prepared for Rails 3.x and I am working on 4.0
 Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

That error message says that objects you've used in the `form_for` is either nil or empty i.e. you haven't defined them.  Since you haven't posted your `show` action try adding the following (Assuming you have the relationship between `article` and `comment` already setup):

```
# ArticlesController

def show 
  @article = Article.find(params[:id]) # However you are retrieving your @article  
  @comment = @article.comments.build
end
```

Comment: @jvnill, Thanks for the edit, don't know why I forgot about that :).

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
def create
    article_id = params[:comment].delete(:article_id)
    @article = Article.find(article_id)
    @comment = @article.comments.build(params[:comment])        

    @comment.save

    redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
  end
```